# Why is (2 sin 5x cos 5x) (2 sin x cos x) = sin 10x sin 2x?

Tags: trigonometry

The question says it all, why? Also, those are not powers, all of them are co-efficient, thanks.

PS This is actually not a homework, was  a solved example I was going through and I got confused.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: This is actually not a homework, was  a solved example I was going through and I got confused.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi Is is still confusing with the answer below?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Nono, solved, thanks for asking. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a simple formula which says

$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

In your question this formula is applied twice